# is time.time() thread specific?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Is `time.time()` in python 2.7 function thread specific or a global function ?? I mean't
to say for example I have the following common function for threads:

```
 while True:
      Now_time=time.time()
      # Some Work thread Does
      Time_Taken_by_Thread=time.time()-Now_time
```

Is this correct in the sense will it help me calculate the time a thread took , does it also
consider the time for which the thread was pre-emptied and was not running ?

Comment: Your final use of Now_time () should not have the brackets.

Comment: yes, silly mistake now corrected thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.time ()` returns time in seconds since the epoch. So, it doesn't matter if your thread was blocked. It's just the time since the epoch in both calls. So in this case it's the total time that elapsed between those two calls..

You can read about [time.time ()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) and [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: so if my thread only ran for 3 sec and was blocked for 5 sec time_taken_by _thread would be 8 sec ??

Comment: That's the way it works - you can read about time.time () and you can read about unix time - I'll put in the links in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The difference between 2 `time.time()`s is only useful for measuring elapsed time